# A question on the interpretation of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I am given a linear map $T(v)$, where:

$v = (x,y,z)^T$ and $T(v) = T((x,y,z)^T) = (2z,x,x+y)^T$

I am confused on how to interpret this. I will now aim to describe some matters that confuse me.

Consider the interpretation of our initial vector $v$ through the standard basis:

$v = (x,y,z)^T = x*(1,0,0)^T+y*(0,1,0)^T+z*(0,0,1)^T = x*e_1+y*e_2+z*e_3$

Also, if we approach the mapping with the standard basis:

$T(v)=T(x*e_1+y*e_2+z*e_3)=T(x*e_1)+T(y*e_2)+T(z*e_3)=x*T(e_1)+y*T(e_2)+z*T(e_3)=x*(0,1,1)^T+y*(0,0,1)^T+z*(2,0,0)^T=(2z,x,x+y)^T=T(v)$

So everything is all good and consistent.

However, as if I understand correctly, a vector like $v = (x,y,z)^T$ represents, in the general case:

$v = x*v_1+y*v_2+z*v_3$

where $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are $3$ vectors that form a basis four our space. So set:

$v = (x,y,z)^T= x*v_1+y*v_2+z*v_3$

and now let: $v_1=(1,1,0)^T, v_2=(0,1,1)^T, v_3=(1,1,1)^T $

So we get:

$v=(x,y,z)^T=x*(1,1,0)^T+y*(0,1,1)^T+z*(1,1,1)^T$

Then it should follow:

$T(v)=T((x,y,z)^T)=T(x*(1,1,0)^T+y*(0,1,1)^T+z*(1,1,1)^T)$

Yet:

$T((x,y,z)^T)=(2z,x,x+y)^T$

And:

$RHS=T(x*(1,1,0)^T)+T(y*(0,1,1)^T)+T(z*(1,1,1)^T))=x*(0,1,2)^T+y*(2,0,1)^T+z(2,1,2)^T=(2y+2z,x+z,2x+y+2z)^T$

These do not equate. So which one is correct: the secondly stated, transformed version of the linear map?

I know that the matrix representation of a linear mapping depends on the basis we are working with. However, in this case, we haven't defined any matrices yet and there seems to be ambiguity.

Where I am getting lost? Thank you!

Comment: If you change basis, then the coordinate vector for $v$ will change. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ the coordinate vector of $e_1$ relative to the standard basis is $(1,0)$, but relative to the nonstandard basis $\{- e_1, e_2\}$ the coordinate vector of $e_1$ is $(-1,0)$.

Comment: They may not have written down a matrix, but effectively the information they gave you was the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis.  You have discovered why one should always specify a basis or assume the standard basis: if you try to use this same rule with respect to every basis, you can't make it consistent.  So, assume the standard basis.  A matrix is just a way of organizing and working with the coefficients they gave you, in this case $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&2\\1&0&0\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The components of a vector are  dependent from the basis. So the vector $\vec v$ tha has components $(x,y,z)^T$ in th standard basis, has components $(y-z,y-x,x-y+z)^T$ in the other basis.